# Correct use of multiple windows for MVC pattern with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, canvas, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a Python program with a GUI in which various animations will be displayed on a canvas. I decided to use a MVC pattern and Tkinter. When launching my program, a window should pop and you have to choose the dimensions of the canvas before displaying the GUI.

[image]

However, I can't find an efficient way to do that. I tried with Dialog, Toplevel, Frame, etc. but as I am using a MVC pattern, I can't find how to link my controller functions with my GUI if this GUI window is opened after the setting window as it is not instantiated yet.

[image]

```
class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.setting_window = SettingWindow(self)
        self.setting_window.ok_button.configure(command=self.open_editor)
        self.withdraw()
        self.mainloop()

    def open_editor(self):
        map_dim = self.setting_window.getValues()
        self.editor_window = Window(self, map_dim)
        self.setting_window.destroy()
```

Comment: You can keep the specs of the GUI set from the popup in a data structure (dict, named tuple, or a custom class), to be used when the GUI is instantiated. You could maybe have this data structure hold default values (maybe read from file) to allow the user to skip the setup step when desired.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to solve this problem was to create a window `Tk()` and just unpacking and packing the different frames. I guess it is not the best way to do it but it worked !